# Finding a meromorphic function with a given singular set...

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{p_j\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that:
$$|p_j|<|p_{j+1}|$$ and $$\lim_{j \to \infty}|p_j| = \infty$$

Does there exist a meromorphic function $f$ on $\Bbb C$ whose singular set is the given sequence, and which has simple poles at each element of the sequence? If so, construct such a function.

I do not have the Mittag-Leffler theorem at my disposal.

I think the answer should be yes, as the sequence is not clustering at infinity. However, I am unsure how to most naturally construct this function. Most trivial ideas I have constructed fail.

Comment: If you just need the existence of such a function, all you need is Mittag-Leffler theorem …unfortunately it is not a constructive result

Comment: If you do not have the Mittag-Leffler theorem at your disposal, you have to mimic the proof of it.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Weierstrass factorization theorem?